# Android get checked ListView items

Tags: android, listview, simpleadapter

I have a Listview with a CheckBox and some Textviews and i'm trying to get all the checked items. I'm using a SimpleAdapter and could not find any helpful tutorial for it. Is there any way to do it with a SimpleAdapter?

Comment: You can actually share a bit of code that you have written so we can see where you are;

Answer (score 0):

You can display checked items of listview like this :

When a listview item is checked,it appends the item to the Textview and removes when the item is unchecked.

```
ArrayList<String> selectedNames = new ArrayList<String>(); 
//Initialise selctnts in onCreate().
selctnts=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selectedtagcontact);
public class CheckBoxClick implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    int listlength;
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {

        CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView) view;
        String item = adapter.getItem(position);
        if (ctv.isChecked()) {
            ctv.setChecked(true);
            selectedNames.add(ctv.getText().toString());
            selctnts.append(item+", ");
        } else {
            ctv.setChecked(false);
            selectedNames.remove(ctv.getText().toString());
            listlength=selectedNames.size();
            selctnts.setText("");
            for(int l=0;l<listlength;l++)
                selctnts.append(selectedNames.get(l)+", ");
        }
    }
}
```